# Right-aligned width modifier in scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

For an assignment, a small portion of it indicates that an integer must only be five digits long. If an integer is entered such as 1234567, then the result should be 34567.

Is there any way that I can set this directly with scanf? Of course, setting it to only read five integers is easy, but it won't read the right-most five. Is there a flag or something that can be set for this, or do I have to do some hackish loops afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the mod operator. `int m = enteredNumber % 100000;` This will truncate your number down.

Here.. I tried it.

```
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char* number = "12334567";

  int numberAsInt = atoi(number);

  int shorterNumber = numberAsInt % 100000;

  printf("The number is %d\n", shorterNumber);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if they enter a number of seven digits -- I had tried that. Or it is working now.... weird?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this

```
char* number = "1234567";
int val = 0;
int len = 0;
int ofset = 0;

len = strlen(number);
if ( len > 5) {
    ofset = len - 5;
}
sscanf(number + ofset, "%d", &val);
printf("result: %d", val);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such predefined quantifier to have the right most digits. you have to write your own loops for displaying the output you want.